# nvd3 Change the chart width (wrapper div of chart) after the chart is paint the chart doesnt refreshed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I trying to change the chart's width according to some parametres I get from server.

The chart width is changed ( I can see that by inspecting the element) but doesnt change in the UI.

```
 <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <nvd3 options="options2" data="data2"></nvd3>
      </div>
 </div>

div.outer { overflow: scroll; }
div.outer .inner { width: 500px; }

$scope.clickme = function(){
    var chartWidth = peopleNumbers * 200000 + "px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.width = chartWidth;
}
```

if i set it to conastant somethimes it refresh in UI too

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.width = "20000px";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to be more flexible try to use the follwoing:
https://jsfiddle.net/d0ogL90d/2/

```
//Width and height
var w = 50000;
var h = 500;
var padding = 50;
```

you can change the width dynamically without problems